# How to deal with the return value which are new line and special symbol in C?

Tags: c, string, split

Here is a newbie's question, I have a return value which have two new line and some special symbol.

But I only want to get the specific part of above-mentioned value.

There is a simple example that base on my code.

When I use C to execute the command, I will get the format of return value like...

Code:

```
fp = popen("cfg get+myvalue", "r");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp); //First Line
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp); // Sec Line
```

Return Value:

```
get+myvalue
+Value: "123456789"
```

For now, I had already try strtok_r(). It actually can divide into two parts (+Value: & "123456789").

But I wanna know is there any more efficient way to get 123456789 without double quote?

I only want to fetch the part of 123456789. Is there any good solution to solve this issue?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is very easy using `strchr` and `strrchr`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "+Value: & \"123456789\"";
    char *start = NULL, *end = NULL;

    start = strchr(str, '"');
    if (start != NULL)
    {
        end = strrchr(++start, '"');
        if (end != NULL)
        {
            *end = '\0';
        }
    }
    if (start && end)
    {
        puts(start);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
123456789
```

Comment: ( - : Thanks a lot. I will give it a try later.

Comment: It works.  Thank you. I will vote this reply as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

like that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    char t[] = R"(vte
ok "lp")", x, q[200]={0};
    sscanf(t,"%*[^\"]%*c%[^\"]" ,q);
    std::cout << q << std::endl;
}
```

warning: non-C code

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I already found the answer. :-)

Comment: really you didn't